# Google maps v3 info window under markers z-index

Tags: google-maps-api-3, infowindow

We are using markers and infowindows on google maps v3 on http://www.stolencamerafinder.com/lostandfound.jsp.

Most of the time the infowindow appears as the top layer. I.e. the full window for one pin is displayed over the other pins on the map.

Occasionally the infowindow appears beneath the pins as in the screenshot below. 
[image]

Is there a way of preventing this from happening?

We are using Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a problem with Google Chrome.  I found your question while trying to solve our similar problem - we have a similar issue with this site:

http://nearbynow.co/air-conditioning/az/scottsdale

It works fine in both ie9 (go figure) and firefox 7, but in chrome, the map markers that are added to the map after the initial map population almost always show above the infobox.  We are adding the infobox to the floatPane, which should always be above the overlayImage pane, where the markers are supposed to be.